# How to install the Gimp normal maps add on for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: plugins, gimp

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and need to install the following gimp add on:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gimp-normalmap

Not sure how to do this, any advice is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Gimp are you on? 2.8 or 2.10?

Comment: Gimp 2.8 
Should I update to 2.10?

Comment: 2.10 is a major overhaul (IMHO it should have been named 3.0). On the whole, much better/pwoerful but plenty of little quirks. Compatibility of some plugins isn't guaranteed. If you stick to your 2.8,  download the `.deb` and `sudo apt install /path/to/packagename.deb`.

Comment: I apologize but don't understand how to do that.

I am thinking since it is a command path that I use the terminal to install it?

What is a .deb file exactly? Is that the actual file or package that I am trying to install via the terminal? Also I don't see a .deb file on that page. There are a lot of links to things but I don't see anything that is a .deb or a path associated.

Forgive my lack of knowledge - brand new to ubuntu. Thank you immensely.

Comment: The page has a `Download gimp-normalmap` section. Since you are likely running a 64-bit Linux you click on the `amd64` link in the "architecture" column. That page tells you how to install an additional repository (recommended option) or download the .deb (click on any of the mirrors). This makes you download a `.deb` file. if you go that route, right clicking the `.deb` in any GUI file manager will likely have an option to install it.

Comment: thank you that is very helpful. For hardware I am running i-8700 chipset/ z-370-g asus board - nvidia 1080ti - would opt for an i386 option instead of the amd64.

Does i386 mean that it is that intel verison or "higher"?

thank you very much

Comment: Intel and AMD are the same instructions set. It only happens that AMD was the first to go 64bit, so the 64-bit Linux is called "amd64" but it runs on Intel as well. So, 32-bit: i386 and 64-bit: amd64. If you install from a repo, this detail is taken care of for you.

Answer (score 1):

The page has a `Download gimp-normalmap` section. Since you are likely running a 64-bit Linux you click on the "amd64"(*) link in the "architecture" column.

That page in turn tells you how to install an additional repository (recommended option). If you do so, `sudo apt update` (to refresh repository info) followed by `sudo apt install gimp-normalmap` will install the plugin (with the right architecture for your installed system).

If you want to be more "manual", click any of the mirrors to download the `.deb` file from it. Then right-clicking the .deb in any GUI file manager will likely have an option to install it.

Side note: Gimp 2.10 is a major overhaul (IMHO it should have been named 3.0). On the whole, it is much better/powerful than 2.8 but still has plenty of little quirks, that will eventually be ironed out. Compatibility of some plugins isn't guaranteed. 2.9 was a development version, and as such has more debug features, isn't performance enhanced, still misses some functionality, and will complain about the use of any deprecated stuff. No point using 2.9 if you are on 18.04.

(*) "amd64" is just the name of the architecture for 64-bit Intel/AMD processors because AMD invented it first. It runs on processor from both  manufacturers.